# Failed to build nativescript-google-maps-sdk

Tags: nativescript-vue

I'm using the **google-maps-sdk plugin in my app (nativescript-vue)**. But when I try to build the project for android I get an error which says

> "Failed to build the plugin nativescript-google-maps-sdk".

I tried everything I found on the net forums since 4 days, I'm trying but the same error persists. please help.

---

Here is the error:

```
Where:

Build file '/home/mhady/Documents/Realtime_Location/platforms/tempPlugin/nativescript_google_maps_sdk/build.gradle' line: 38

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'nativescript_google_maps_sdk'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Failed to build plugin nativescript-google-maps-sdk : 
Error: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1
```

`

Comment: Can you tell us more about the error and what solutions did you try?